# Encode String to UCS2

Tags: java

I need to encode java string to UCS like 'h' to '0068'

eg. I have a test setup

```
@Test
public void testEncodeAsUCS2_string1() throws Exception {
    String encoded = sendRequestTransformer.encodeAsUCS2("hello");
    Assert.assertEquals("00680065006C006C006F", encoded);
}
```

so this test lets me know if the conversion was successful eg. hello should return 00680065006C006C006F

In my code I have the following conversion which I know is wrong as it prints [B@742cb491. (This toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object)

I need help with the conversion

```
String encodeAsUcx2(String messageContent){

                            try {
                                            messageContent.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return String.valueOf(messageContent.getBytes());

            }
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

After you convert your message to a `byte[]`, you just need to loop through and convert each `byte` to a hex representation, and build a new `String` as you go.

For instance, you could do something like this:

```
static String encodeAsUcs2(String messageContent) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = messageContent.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

I should note, however, that this will return `"680065006C006C006F00"`, not `"00680065006C006C006F"` when encoding `"hello"`.

To get the output you're expecting, you would need to use big-endian encoding (`"UTF-16BE"`).

Comment: Thanks that works for normal English words but I am having problem with different words in different languages. It results in the the letters being outputed as FFFD which is used to indicate when a system is unable to render a stream of data to a corect symbol

Comment: @user3520080 Can you give an example?  It's possible that you're trying to encode something not supported by UTF-16, and need to use one of the [other encodings support by Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) instead.

Comment: You can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE` instead of `"UTF-16LE"`